# how to read/ignore the contents of a single line in php?

Tags: php

i have the following PHP and HTML code,

```
      <?PHP

            $filename = 'txt.txt';
        $str = file_get_contents($filename);
          $data = explode("\n", $str);
       $data2 = explode(":", $data[0]);
       $data3 = explode(":", $data[1]);

         $first_name = $data2[1];

        $age = $data3[1];
             ?>

         <html>
        <body>
           name:<input id="abc1" onload="InputValidate1()" value="<?php echo $first_name ?>" >  </input>

          age:<input id="abc" onload="InputValidate()" value="<?php echo $age ?>" >              </input>

        </body>
        </html>
```

and the text file 'txt.txt' contents are:

```
              name:jon
              age:25
```

i get the output as above,
but i want to get the same output with following contents in the text file,

```
           -----details-----
             name:jon
            ----cont----
              age:25
```

i.e. i want to ignore those lines in between and display only the useful contents, how to read/ignore the contents of a single line in php ? or is there any other way to achieve this ?

Comment: I would suggest to _parse_ the text file line by line. When you see `--` at the beginning, ignore that line; when you see `name:` at the beginning, treat the string behind the `:` as name; `age:` and treat as age. This way you can have more flexibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use preg_match to match lines that begin with "-" and unset them from array.

```
  <?php

        $filename = 'txt.txt';
    $str = file_get_contents($filename);

    $data = explode("\n", $str);
    foreach ($data as $key => $line) {
        if(preg_match('/^-/', $line)){
            echo "match $line";
            unset($data[$key]);
        }
    }

    $data2 = explode(":", $data[1]);
   $data3 = explode(":", $data[3]);

     $first_name = $data2[1];

    $age = $data3[1];
    ?>
     <html>
    <body>
       name:<input id="abc1" onload="InputValidate1()" value="<?php echo $first_name ?>" >  </input>

      age:<input id="abc" onload="InputValidate()" value="<?php echo $age ?>" >              </input>

    </body>
    </html>
```